# Prove: Number of (not necessarily primes) not fulfilling Fermats little theorem exceed $\frac{1}{2}\varphi(n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function

Show for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$
\#\{\bar a \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times \,\,|\,\, \bar a^{n-1}  \neq \bar1 \} \ge \frac{1}{2}\varphi(n)
$$

given at least one $a \in (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ with $ \bar a^{n-1}  \neq \bar1.$